# Dropzone js can't get addEventListener when clicked on button in FireFox

Tags: dropzone.js

I tried to solve the problem but I can't.
When upload a file in to FireFox I can not uploaded,
but file will uploading in to Opera okay.
Along Dropzone.js I used bootstrap and jquery as library.

In my opinion the problem is addEventListener?
Example video with a firebug: [enter link description here](http://www.dailymotion.com/video/x2zhb5m)

Snippet:

```js
Dropzone.options.myDropzone = {

  // Prevents Dropzone from uploading dropped files immediately
  autoProcessQueue: false,
  parallelUploads: 10,
  thumbnailWidth: 120,
  thumbnailHeight: 120,
  init: function() {

   var submitButton = document.querySelector("#submit-all");
   var myDropzone = this;

    submitButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
       myDropzone.processQueue(); // Tell Dropzone to process all queued files.
      });

       this.on("addedfile", function(file) {
           // Create the remove button
           var removeButton = Dropzone.createElement("<button class='btn btn-xs btn-warning'>Remove file</button>");

           // Listen to the click event
           removeButton.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
             // Make sure the button click doesn't submit the form:
             e.preventDefault();
             e.stopPropagation();

           // Remove the file preview.
           myDropzone.removeFile(file);
           //   // If you want to the delete the file on the server as well,
           //   // you can do the AJAX request here.
           });

           // Add the button to the file preview element.
           file.previewElement.appendChild(removeButton);
    });
    
  } //dropzone init
 }; //dropzone options
```

```html
<script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/enyo/dropzone/master/dist/dropzone.js"></script>

<form action="upload/do_upload" class="dropzone" id="my-dropzone"></form>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"><span id="submit-all">Submit all files</span></button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default"><a href="upload">Reset</a></button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you have a SPAN id="submit-all"

`<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"><span id="submit-all">Submit all files</span></button>`

Then you have a querySelector for it:

`var submitButton = document.querySelector("#submit-all");`

Buttons have a click event, not spans. Maybe if you change the first line to this it should work:

`<button type="button" id="submit-all" class="btn btn-primary"><span>Submit all files</span></button>`

Give it a try and let us know.

Comment: +Guilherme Melo For now, is passed long time, about 8 months ago. I do not use dropzone anymore. And I don't know what I do now? Maybe this question useful for someone? Thanks for your answer and really sorry. If question did not useful - how deleted it?